Sylow subgroups of semidirect products
Suppose that $G = A \times B$ is a direct product of finite groups $A$ and $B$. Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. We have an epimorphism from $G$ to $A$ so that the image of $P$ in $A$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $A$. The same occurs with $B$. From the orders, I think a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ is the direct product of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $A$ with $B$.
What about $G = A \rtimes_{\varphi} B$? Is it true that a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ is of the form $P_A \rtimes P_B$ for Sylow $p$-subgroups $P_A$ of $A$ and $P_B$ of $B$?

The question is unclear. It is true that there exists a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ of that form, but it is not necessarily true that all Sylow $p$-subgroups have that form.

The answer is no, consider for example $p = 2$ and $G = S_3 = C_3 \rtimes C_2$.
But it is true that there exists a Sylow $p$-subgroup of the form $P_A \rtimes P_B$, where $P_A$ is a $p$-Sylow of $A$, and $P_B$ is a $p$-Sylow of $B$. The proof of this is a good exercise (using Sylow's theorem) which I leave for you to consider.

That depends on how you interpret "... a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ has the form ...".

@DerekHolt: Sure, as you say it is a bit unclear. I took the interpretation that we identify $B$ with ${(1,b) : b \in B}$ in the semidirect product, and $A$ with ${(a,1) : a \in A}$.

In this example all the Sylow's are conjugates of $P_A \rtimes P_B$ by $P_A$ (of course they are all conjugates in general, but by $G$). Is that true in general?

I don't understand the "good exercise", $P_A \rtimes P_B$ obviously has the correct size

@ronno: It has the correct size, but you need to assume that $P_B$ normalizes $P_A$ for it to be a subgroup. (And for the notation $P_A \rtimes P_B$ to make sense.) It is not always true that $P_B$ normalizes every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $A$.
